# "walking recovery in patients who suffered a stroke" or "the recovery of the ability to walk in patients who suffered a stroke"?

Tags: idiomatic-language, register

Tell me please which phrasing sounds more natural in the following context:

> The necessary information can be found in the article with the title ***WALKING RECOVERY IN PATIENTS WHO SUFFERED A STROKE.***
>
> The necessary information can be found in the article with the title ***THE RECOVERY OF THE ABILITY TO WALK IN PATIENTS WHO SUFFERED A STROKE***.

I am not sure any of the variants for the article title sounds native. Tell me please what would be the natural title for the article on relearning to walk after a stroke.

Comment: Is the article intended for a lay audience, or specialists?

Comment: Rather, for specialists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titles typically avoid restrictive relative clauses like "who have suffered a stroke"

*Learning to Walk Again after a Stroke*  <sup>lay audience</sup>

You should check the intended journal and see if articles refer to "walking" or "ambulation". The title of an article for specialists might also avoid the word "stroke".

Comment: Would it sound ok for specialists if I rephrase it like "The recovery of the ability to walk after a stroke"?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20805757